# Making a button go to its initial state

Tags: jquery, html, less

Right now I've gotten to the part of styling the video controls in my site and I've encountered a small problem.

The video section contains a video-list and a video player. Whenever an `li` element from the list is clicked the video-player's source changes to that of the video clicked. There is  a play button on top of the video player which has a transition from play to pause.

The problem I've encountered is that whenever the video source changes the button doesn't go back to the play state.

HTML code (`index.php`):

```
<div class="control play">
    <span class="left"></span><span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

This is the less styling of the button (`Less.less`):

```
.control {
    @color: #ffb160;
    @highlight: darken(@color, 10%);
    @duration: 0.4s;
    @sin:  0.866;
    @size: 30px;
    border: @size*0.1 solid @color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: @size*0.25;
    width: @size;
    height: @size;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;

    &, .left, .right, &:before {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transition: border @duration, width @duration, height @duration, margin @duration;
        transition-tiomig-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    &:before {
        content: "";
        height: @size;
    }

    &.pause {
        .left, .right {
            margin: 0;
            border-left: @size*0.33 solid @color;
            border-top: 0 solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
            height: @size*@sin;
        }
        .left {
            border-right: @size*0.2 solid transparent;
        }
    }

    &.play {
        @border: @size/4;
        .left {
            margin-left: @size/6;
            border-left: @size*@sin/2 solid @color;
            border-top: @border solid transparent;
            border-bottom: @border solid transparent;
            border-right: 0px solid transparent;
            height: @size - 2*@border;
        }
        .right {
            margin: 0;
            border-left: @size*@sin/2 solid @color;
            border-top: @border solid transparent;
            border-bottom: @border solid transparent;
            height: 0px;
         }
    }

    &:hover {
        border-color: @highlight;
        .left, .right {
            border-left-color: @highlight;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the transition from play to pause (`JQuery.js`):

```
$(".control").on('mousedown', function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
        $(this).toggleClass('pause play');
        video.play();
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('play pause');
        video.pause();
    }
});
```

This is the event triggered by clicking a li element from the list (`JQuery.js`):

```
$('.video-element').click(function(){
    var videosource = $(this).find("div.source").html();
    var imgsource = $(this).find(".video-thumbnails").attr("src");

    $(".control").toggleClass('play');
    document.getElementById('video-player').setAttribute('poster',imgsource);
    document.getElementById('mp4').setAttribute('src','videos/'+videosource + ".mp4");
    document.getElementById('ogv').setAttribute('src','videos/'+videosource + ".ogv");
    document.getElementById('webm').setAttribute('src','videos/'+videosource + ".webm");
    $("#video-player").load();
});
```

What I've tried so far is adding `$(".control").toggleClass('play');` to the code regarding the change of the video which doesn't work because the button changes either to pause or play every time I click on a new video.

Comment: Try adding a FIDDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the source of the video, can you also change the class of the play/pause button? That is, in your 'click' function, include

1. code to change the source of the video *(done)*.
2. code to change button class to 'play' (using `$(elem).setClass("play")` or something similar).

Comment: thanks all i needed to do was replace **$(".control").toggleClass('play');** with **$(".control").attr('class','control play');**